# Linq Xelement and Class

Tags: c#, linq, xelement

So, let me explain my trouble.

I get a project which was develop by another guy, and he leaved the firm. Now i have to update the program but something going wrong when i import the solution.

Let see the code:

```
  ListeDeTypeDePoste = (from e in xml.Descendants("profil")
                              select new TypeDePoste()
                              {
                                  Nom = e.Element("name").Value,
                                  Chaines = (from c in e.Elements("Chaine")
                                             select new Chaine()
                                             {
                                                 Code = c.Element("Code")?.Value,
                                                 Type = c.Element("Type")?.Value,
                                                 Nom = c.Element("Nom")?.Value,
                                                 OU = c.Element("OU")?.Value
                                             }).ToList()
                              }).ToList<TypeDePoste>();
```

The trouble is on the `.?Value` for each properties in a Chaine Class, when i debug i can even debug the solution and if i remove them i got a  NullReferenceException. With this code the previous realese .exe worked like a charm

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: So what is your question? If for one of the `c.Element("...")` it returns with `null` and you remove the `?.` then of course it'll throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the operator `?.` only in `C# 6.0`.

This is `null-propagation` operator. If you don't want to use it, you can change your assignment to properties of `Chaine` class:

```
select new Chaine()
{
    Code = (c.Element("Code") == null) ? null : c.Element("Code").Value,
    Type = (c.Element("Type") == null) ? null : c.Element("Type").Value,
    Nom = (c.Element("Nom") == null) ? null : c.Element("Nom").Value,
    OU = (c.Element("OU") == null) ? null : c.Element("OU").Value
}).ToList()
```

If you delete `?` in this operator the assignment will crash because you try to get value of `null`.

If c.Element("Code") is null then this code will simply assign null to Code:

```
Code = c.Element("Code")?.Value;
```

But without `?`:

```
Code = c.Element("Code").Value; //app will throw an exception because c.Element("Code") is null
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `Element` calls in that code are sometimes returning `null`, because an element with the given name doesn't exist at that location in the XML document you're processing.

The `?.` ([null-conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn986595.aspx)) operator tests for this, returning `null` in such a scenario.

If you use `.` instead (without adding your own `null` check), then a *NullReferenceException* will be thrown in such a scenario. This is by-design in C#.

The null-conditional operator was [introduced in C# 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx), so to use it you'll need to install Visual Studio 2015.